# Add usable tick box to django admin (for boolean)

Tags: django, django-admin

I would like a way to change boolean values in django admin.

Django displays a green/red box for when it is on/off, however if does not give you an option to change the value without entering each individual item.

How is this achieved?

A screenshot of it seemingly being done.

[image: A screenshot of it seemingly being done.]

Comment: Have you tried `list_editable` and this looks really broad can you post related piece of code?

Comment: Brilliant- that did it perfectly. Is it only for boolean values?

Comment: You can apply on other fields also than bool, have fun.

Comment: If you have another question then you should ask it as a new question (include what you have tried/researched so far)